# Is layover time of 1hr and 5 min enough at Vienna International Airport to catch the next connecting flight?

Tags: air-travel, layovers, cancellations, fra, vie

I am travelling to San Francisco, and my itinerary has two layovers, first leg of the journey is from DEL(Delhi) to Vienna (layover 1 hour 5 min) the second leg is from Vienna to Frankfurt (layover 1 hour 20 min) and final flight from FRA to SFO.

I am panicking over the fact that if a layover of 1hour 5min and 1 hour 20 min respectively would be enough for me to make my connection flights.

Please let me know if I should take the risk or cancel and reschedule my flight.

Edit- My flight arrives at Vienna international airport and leaves from the same, and for second leg it arrives at Frankfurt international airport. **Also I do not have to collect the luggage as the entire journey is via Lufthansa.**

Comment: Is it one ticket?

Comment: Yes, I have one ticket and the entire journey is via Lufthansa airline. I have edited the original post as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have one ticket, you don't have to worry. If you miss your connection you will get transferred to the next available flight. Also most flights these days arrive ahead of time.

There is [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/5859/141) epic answer that explains this in detail.

Comment: I am aware of this, but my biggest concern stems from the fact that- I have to be back in San Fran on a specific day so I can not afford to miss the connection flight. =

Comment: In that case I would contact Lufthansa for advise. I assume since they offer you that connection they will make sure you can make it. Also lengthy delays from your journey will cost them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Also do I need schengen visa(or any visa) since my flight is from Vienna to Frankfurt

Comment: That is a different question I would ask as a seperate question

Comment: @rg.us If you do have to be back back at a specific date, just travel one day earlier ...

Comment: That is seemingly hard now that I have my tickets booked, I know I committed a stupid mistake in the spur of the moment to save $50 by booking this ticket but there's little I can do now.

Comment: Just wait and see. Don't stress. If it happens, everything will go smoothly ...

Comment: If things go wrong you are at least entitled to 450 EUR

Comment: Thanks @Andra it was really helpful. Also what's this 450 EUR that you just mentioned, I might as well make lemonade out of all the lemons that this itinerary has been throwing at me.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is that airlines set their minimum connect times at a level that is possible if everything goes well but leaves very little room for delays.

I would be most worried about the layover in Vienna for two reasons.

1. An intercontinental flight is far more likely to be significantly delayed than an intra-europe one
2. You will have to go through Schengen entry immigration there (I'm guessing you aren't an EU/EEA/Swiss citizen, so will have to go through the "all passports" queue).

If you are on one ticket and you are delayed by airports/airlines (and I think in most cases immigration too) then the airline will make new arrangements for you to travel to your destination, but there may be a significant delay.

P.S. If you are an Indian citizen be aware that you will need a Schengen Visa for this itinary.