# Travelling from India to Ukraine. Do I need Transit Visa for Vienna?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, vie

I am traveling from Delhi to Kiev( Ukraine) via Vienna. Do I need a transit Visa? Transit time is 2 hrs.  I hold an Indian passport and Visa for Ukraine.

Comment: Duplicate http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/17385/4584