# Do US citizens need a visa for transit in Frankfurt?

Tags: visas, schengen, us-citizens

I am a US citizen.  I have a transit in Frankfurt for 12 and half hours. I will fly from Detroit to Frankfurt then to Amman, Jordan.  I was planning to stay at the airport hotel, but I was wondering whether I need a visa to leave the airport?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is a Schengen visa/transit visa required for transit flight from Vienna to Frankfurt?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17385/is-a-schengen-visa-transit-visa-required-for-transit-flight-from-vienna-to-frank)

Comment: It seems to me that there are two different questions here: First, do you need to pass immigration, second, do you need a visa. I would guess that the answer to the first question is affirmative (and maybe you also assumed this, but then the title of your question is slightly misleading), and Greg has answered the second question.

Answer (score 11):

No, US citizens do not need a visa to enter the Schengen area. You may stay for up to 90 days in any 180 day period without a visa.

For further information, see [Visa policies in the European Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policies_in_the_European_Union).

Answer (score 2):

Nope.  As seen from the [first hit in google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Do%20US%20citizens%20need%20a%20visa%20for%20transit%20in%20Frankfurt?), only [a few countries require transit visas in Germany](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05__Legal/02__Directory__Services/01__Visa/__Transit__Visa.html), and none of them are the US.

The list of countries are:

> AFGHANISTAN, BANGLADESH, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO, ERITREA,
>   ETHIOPIA, GHANA, INDIA, IRAN, IRAQ, JORDAN ** (please see below),
>   LEBANON, MYANMAR, MALI, NIGERIA, PAKISTAN, SOMALIA, SRI LANKA, SUDAN,
>   SOUTH SUDAN, SYRIA, TURKEY

although it should be noted that there are other cases for even those countries whereby they may not require one (eg if they have a US visa in their passport - go figure!).

Comment: There is also a special provision for Jordanian citizens.