# Transiting Brussels, after having lost your passport in the USA

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, brussels

My son is returning from USA to India By Jet Air Ways Via Brussels.

He had lost his Indian Passport in USA While studying on F1 Visa. He has obtained duplicate passport from Indian consulate and also I94 from Department of Homeland Security in USA. He has duly reported this to Florida police and US Consulate in India. But his duplicate passport does not have stamped visas. However he is now on H1b status and has all the immigration documents. Can my son use Brussels as a transit point while flying back to India?

Comment: long as he remains airside, nobody will likely care. If he doesn't, he's going to need an EU visa, and again nobody cares about his US visa which is irrelevant in the EU.

Answer (score 2):

Indian citizens do not need a visa to transit in Brussels (assuming your son is doing it on one ticket and can check his luggage through so that he won't need to leave the transit lounge of the airport), see [Transit visa for Brussels for Indian citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27688/transit-visa-for-brussels-for-indian-citizens)

Consequently, an Indian passport should be enough, a US visa or evidence of his status there is not required in this direction. It would however be required to transit, e.g., in Germany and in that case I am not sure he could do it without applying for a German airport transit visa. But fortunately, it's not the case in Belgium so the point is moot.

See also [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area) for a complete rundown of the rules and official sources for all that.