# Transit visa for an adult and infant (MIA-ZRH-FRA-IKA)

Tags: visas, transit, children, us-citizens, iranian-citizens

My nationality is Iranian; I hold an Iranian passport, but I am living in the United States and have a green card, too. My baby is American, and she has American and Iranian passports.

I have a ticket from Miami to Zurich, then to Frankfurt, and then to Tehran, and will return from Tehran to Frankfurt, and then Frankfurt to Miami.

I want to know do if I need a transit visa or any other visa for this travel or not. My layovers are not more than five hours.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17385/is-a-schengen-visa-transit-visa-required-for-transit-flight-from-vienna-to-frank?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, your daughter.  As she has both USA and Iranian passports she can enter all countries on your trip, so she does not need any visas.

However your situation is a little more difficult.

As an Iranian citizen with a US green card you are allowed to "Transit Without Visa" airports in both Switzerland and Germany.

HOWEVER, TWOV is only available when you are connecting from a flight that originated outside of the [Schengen area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area) AND connecting to a flight that is destined to an area outside of the Schengen area.  For your itinerary, this is NOT the case.  In order to catch your Zurich to Frankfurt flight you will need to pass through passport control, and enter the Schengen area.  Your flight to Frankfurt is then similar to a "domestic" flight, after which you will need to once again go through passport control to leave the Schengen region for your flight to Tehran.

Not only is this not allowed under TWOV, it's also not allowed using a Transit Visa as you will be leaving the airport whilst in the Schengen area (during your flight from Zurich to Frankfurt)

Thus you WILL need to apply for a visa, and specifically you will need a short-stay visa (not a transit visa).

You may find it easier to change your flights such that you only pass through a single Schengen country, in which case you would likely not need a visa.  For example, Miami -> Frankfurt -> Tehran would allow you to use TWOV, and thus no visa would be necessary.

Comment: thank you so much , i cheaged my ticket to miami->frankfort->tehran . g.b.u