# Do I need a Schengen Visa to transit in both Amsterdam and Paris on the way flighting from Canada to Vietnam?

Tags: visas, paris, amsterdam, vietnamese-citizens

I am Vietnamese. I am studying in Canada.
In this December I will fly from Canada to Vietnam.
In my fight schedule, I must transit in Amsterdam for 1.5 hours and then in Paris for 3 hours.
I wonder if I need a Schengen Visa to flight from Amsterdam to Paris in my schedule?

Comment: Related question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17385/is-a-schengen-visa-transit-visa-required-for-transit-flight-from-vienna-to-frank

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a flight between two Schengen countries is considered a domestic flight, so you will need to pass border control in order to board your flight from Amsterdam to Paris.

Comment: Can you provide a link for answers like this? It's useful for someone to have their worries cleared with an official website, instead of someone on the internet (not saying you're wrong, just that links help)

Answer (score -3):

You definitely don't need a visa to connect in Amsterdam, as their Schipol is a "single terminal airport". I.e. when you arrive from Canada, you will not cross the borders waiting for your plane to Paris.
In Paris everything depends on the terminals usage: if you depart from a different terminal than arrive from, then there is a chance you would have to cross the borders. 
This would not be a definitive blocker yet: even in such a circumstance, borders officer may grant you a 24-hrs transit visa so you are able to continue your flight. 
However, the best way to do it is to check with your airline.

Comment: -1 the OP will enter the Schengen area in Amsterdam and definitely need a visa

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amsterdam_Airport_Schiphol#Terminal -> Schirpol has only one terminal but 3 departure halls

Comment: And there are airports with just one terminal divided between Schengen and Non-Schengen with border control in between.