# Do I need Schengen visa for transit airports?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, indian-citizens, airports

I am flying from USA to India and transit airport is in Amsterdam and Paris.

Forward journey is USA -> Amsterdam -> India
and return is India -> Paris -> USA.

I am not planning to go outside airport.

Do I need visa even to stay in the airport?

BTW, I am Indian citizen with valid US visa.

I researched some past questions and found that a Schengen visa is needed if flight is between Schengen countries. [Is a Schengen visa/transit visa required for a transit flight through two Schengen airports?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17385/is-a-schengen-visa-transit-visa-required-for-transit-flight-from-vienna-to-frank)

Comment: Welcome, and thank you for researching past questions before asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in a slightly different situation than the Vienna/Frankfurt question as you will not take any flight between two Schengen airports. The fact that you are not taking a flight between Amsterdam and Paris but only stopping at *one* Schengen airport each time (whether it's the same on the way back or not doesn't matter much) does make a difference.

In that case, you don't need to enter the Schengen area and the rules for airside transit apply. And since you have a valid US visa, it means that you can transit without visa. As an Indian citizen, if you did not have a US visa, you would still need an *airport transit visa* in Paris (not in Amsterdam).

[Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area) contains all the details.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It is interesting to know that some people from some countries would need a transit visa in Paris even if the person entering Paris only _once_.

Comment: @gfbs34 when you transit in Paris, you will not pass through immigration control, and an airport transit visa is only for those who will not pass through immigration control.  (The same is true for Amsterdam, but apparently Indians don't need an ATV for the Netherlands as they do for France.)  As Relaxed notes, holders of valid visas from the US (among other countries) are exempted from any requirement to hold an ATV.